# Failed to start netfilter-persistent configuration

Tags: iptables

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and until yesterday I used UFW and had only some basic rules. Now I need to have more complex rules and I decided to use iptables (if I understand right, I can't have my firewall rules in file without it).
Now I see an error for netfilter-persistance.service if I run:
`sudo systemctl status netfilter-persistent.service`

[image: screenshot]

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

First of all check

```
sudo journalctl -e -u netfilter-persistent.service
```

for errors. Then have a look at which are rules being loaded by `netfilter-persistent` service. Which are located in `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` and `/etc/iptables/rules.v6`. The service pretty much just loads firewall rules using:

```
sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

You cat try to debug it line by line (and the same for `rules.v6`). After removing erroneous statement you can restart the service:

```
sudo systemctl restart netfilter-persistent.service
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. At the time of opening the post (some days later), I format the server (for other reasons). But now I have the same problem and found my post. Interesting. Any idea, how can I check the rules.v4 (or rules.v6) for errors? Both are pretty long, so working line by line and restarting the server isn't a good option.